# Setting Exceptions in PhpStorm advanced metadata

Tags: phpstorm

I'm overriding the PHP warning when functions such as `unset()` fail so that they throw an `ErrorException` and make it more explicit that something bad has happened that the programmer needs to deal with. I want PhpStorm to warn me and any other programmer on my project that `unset()` outside of a `try/catch` block has an unhandled `ErrorException`.

I've found the page [PhpStorm advanced metadata](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/ide-advanced-metadata.html) but I don't see anywhere how to say what exceptions get thrown.

This is the only reference to `Exception` I could find on the page, and it's about returning an `Exception`, not throwing an `Exception`:

> ##### Pass a string literal
>
> When the `"special"` string literal is passed, an instance of `\Exception` is returned:
>
> ```php
> override(\Factory::get(), map([
>     "special" => \Exception::class,
> ]));
> ```
>
> [image]

Does PhpStorm allow setting `Exception`s and other `Throwable`s in its `.phpstorm.meta.php` files? If so, how?

Comment: PhpStorm Advanced Metadata is for return values (types), list of applicable parameters, parameter values but not about "what this function may throw". This is what standard PHPDoc `@throws` does just fine. Problem is -- I do not think you can redeclare `unset()` in PhpStorm as it's a special function (language construct basically). But you can try modifying the actual PhpStorm stubs (use your own copy of the https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs ) Check the following link where to set the path to them:  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/php.html#advanced-settings-area

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks! However that doesn't seem like it would be a portable solution. I wouldn't be able to commit the rules to our repository and have them work on another machine. Unless I'm wrong about that?

Comment: Well, cannot do anything about it. The issue is that `unset()` is a special stuff (not an ordinary PHP function), so you cannot redeclare it in an ordinary file. You can try though: Ctrl+Click on `unset()` in your PHP code and it will take you to the default stub file. Copy the whole file content into your project and modify the docs for unset as needed (the file is for IDE eyes only). Will it accept the new stuff? (may warn about/show 2 declarations though)

Comment: I've already got one of those "multiple declarations" warnings for `Throwable` due to the testing framework we use. I don't want more of them! The idea is for the IDE to notify the programmer about important things they should be aware of and address.

Comment: *"...for Throwable due to the testing framework we use."* Which framework is that? In what file that extra declaration is located? can you give me a link to that file on a GitHub? Depending on what that file has it might be possible to remove the duplication.

Comment: *"The idea is for the IDE to notify the programmer about important things they should be aware of and address"* As I'm getting from the question body, You are trying to modify the standard behaviour of a function/lang construct that has special meaning. Sadly it's not that straightforward. In either case: I suggest you try my suggestion first.

Comment: @LazyOne https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/blob/4.2/autoload.php which was removed in https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/blob/5.0/autoload.php in this commit: https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/commit/0db4a0728a46f656601cda81f1c5cde399548869

Comment: Thanks. That's an autoload file, not an actual class definition etc so it's not used for the actual code completion. So what you can do for that v4.2 file is: 1) right click on it in the Project View panel; 2) select "Override File Type" in the context menu 3) apply "Plain Text" type. Now the file will be treated as if it's a plain text and not PHP so the IDE will not index it. hence avoiding the "multiple declarations warning for Throwable". Give it a go. **NOTE:** such an override is stored in the IDE settings and not project.